# why applied template is repeating twice

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

hi i have applied a template  data should to be populate only once, here issue was it was repeating twice can any one suggest to stop that repeatation find the below my sample code of xsl

Here is my XSL:

```
   <xsl:param name="PackageId"  />
  <xsl:template match="/">      
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="SequenceB"  select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="sequenceC"  select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId][position()=1]"/>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template mode ="SequenceB" match="NewDataSet/Table">

    <xsl:choose >

          <xsl:when  test ="substring(./MSG_TYPE_CODE,2,3)= '102'"  >

                <xsl:if test ="./CTD_SEQ_NUM"  >
                    <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select= "concat(':21:',./CTD_SEQ_NUM)" />
                    <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text >
                </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test ="./CURRENCY_CODE" >
                  <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
                  <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':32B:',./CURRENCY_CODE)"/>

              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test ="./CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT" >
                  <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
                  <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "translate(./CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT ,'.',',')"/>
                  <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text >
              </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test ="substring(./MSG_TYPE_CODE,2,3)= '103'">
            <xsl:if test ="./TRAN_TYPE_CODE"  >
                <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select=           "concat(':26T:',./TRAN_TYPE_CODE)" /><xsl:text/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test ="./CTD_VALUE_DATE" >
                <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':32A:',./CTD_VALUE_DATE)"/><xsl:text/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test ="./CURRENCY_CODE" >
                <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "./CURRENCY_CODE"/><xsl:text/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test ="./CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT" >
                <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "translate(./CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT,'.',',')"/><xsl:text/>
            </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 

     <xsl:template mode="sequenceC" match="NewDataSet/Table">

    <xsl:if test ="substring(./MSG_TYPE_CODE,2,3)= '102'">

    <xsl:if test ="./CTD_VALUE_DATE" >
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':32A:',./CTD_VALUE_DATE)"/><xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./CURRENCY_CODE" >
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "./CURRENCY_CODE"/><xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT" >
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "translate(./CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT,'.',',')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text >
    </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
  <RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
  <MSG_TYPE_CODE>O102N</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
  <CTD_SEQ_NUM>000001</CTD_SEQ_NUM>
  <CTD_BEN_INS_ID>ABNAAEAD</CTD_BEN_INS_ID>
  <TRAN_TYPE_CODE>MIS</TRAN_TYPE_CODE>
  <CTD_VALUE_DATE>110911</CTD_VALUE_DATE>
  <CURRENCY_CODE>AED</CURRENCY_CODE>
  <CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT>42404.00</CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT>
  <CTD_INS_AMT>42404.00</CTD_INS_AMT>
  <CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>2</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>    
 </Table>
 <Table>
  <RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
  <MSG_TYPE_CODE>O102N</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
  <CTD_SEQ_NUM>000002</CTD_SEQ_NUM>
 <CTD_BEN_INS_ID>ABNAAEAD</CTD_BEN_INS_ID>
 <TRAN_TYPE_CODE>MIS</TRAN_TYPE_CODE>
 <CTD_VALUE_DATE>110911</CTD_VALUE_DATE>
 <CURRENCY_CODE>AED</CURRENCY_CODE>
 <CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT>154776.75</CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT>
 <CTD_INS_AMT>154776.75</CTD_INS_AMT>
 <CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>2</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>    
 </Table>
<Table>
<RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
<MSG_TYPE_CODE>O102N</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
<CTD_SEQ_NUM>000003</CTD_SEQ_NUM>
<CTD_BEN_INS_ID>ABNAAEAD</CTD_BEN_INS_ID>
<TRAN_TYPE_CODE>MIS</TRAN_TYPE_CODE>
<CTD_VALUE_DATE>110911</CTD_VALUE_DATE>
<CURRENCY_CODE>AED</CURRENCY_CODE>
<CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT>1800.00</CTD_SETLD_TRAN_AMT>
   <CTD_INS_AMT>1800.00</CTD_INS_AMT>
<CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>2</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>    
      </Table>
      </NewDataSet>
```

output:

**:21:000001
:32B:AED42404,00
:21:000001
:32B:AED42404,00
:21:000002
:32B:AED154776,75
:21:000002
:32B:AED154776,75
:21:000003
:32B:AED1800,00
:21:000003
:32B:AED1800,00
:32A:110911AED42404,00**

required output as :

**:21:000001
:32B:AED42404,00
:21:000002
:32B:AED154776,75
:21:000003
:32B:AED1800,00
:32A:110911AED42404,00**

Comment: The XSLT sample isn't currently well-formed. It looks like there is a missing **xsl:if** end-tag in the final template. Could you correct this, so there is no confusion. Also, the XSLT refers to a **CTD_CTD_PKG_ID** element when it applies the template, but this is not actually present in the sample XML. Could you correct this too? Thanks!

Comment: can any one please give some suggestions for which to avoid repeatations

Comment: why the tags getting repeated, kindly give some suggestions to stop it

Answer (score 0):

In your first template you have several times the following line:

```
<xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
```

This line doesn't do anything, code that is to be executed only when the condition is true should go between the tags (as you have done in other places).

Similarly, you have this kind of stuff in a few places:

```
<xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "./CURRENCY_CODE"/><xsl:text/>
```

The `text` tags serve no purpose as they are auto closing.

You should make a round of clean up on the opening/closing of all the tags. Even if the problem does not disappear, it will be a lot easier to analyze.

Comment: can you please make it clear boss... i have removed all the position lines in first template even the data was getting generated repeatedly

Comment: You need to help us help you. Provide the cleaned-up XSLT, one that can actually match on the data you provide (there is no CTD_CTD_PKG_ID in your data, is this the right XSLT? the right source XML?). Make it so that we can test it on our own and see where the problem could be. Also, don't treat it like magic, if the `if` tests were set in the first place, there was probably a reason...

Comment: yeah! i have provide package id in xml boss

Comment: Well, [your](http://pastebin.com/gGZBULW1) XSLT works for me. I get the required output without duplicates. So the issue must be somewhere else. Are you sure you are testing with this very XSLT? Maybe you are testing with an older version where you copy/pasted the first `<xsl:when` block with the test on '102' and not altered it for '103'. It would give the sort of duplication you are seeing…